# Accessing DOM object using AngularJS

Tags: java, spring, angularjs

I have the following code as Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/city/{city}")
    public ModelAndView cityRestaurants(@PathVariable String city){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("restaurant");
    List<Restaurant> list = null;
    try {
        list = rService.getRestaurantsFromCity(city);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mav.addObject("list", list);

    return mav;
    }
```

How can I access "list" on client side using AngularJS?

Comment: make an API request to the REST url and you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @jhadesdev instead of using Model and View approach you can use Restful Web service which returns the data to angular js Controller in JSON format. There you can change your $scope variable as desired depending on the result. For a detailed tutorial you can go spring web site.

1 [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

2 [Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/)

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to define a controller that does not have a view but renders the return parameters as JSON. In order for this to work the Jersey library needs to be on the classpath:

```
@Responsebody
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/city/{city}", produces = "application/json" )
public List<Restaurant> cityRestaurants(@PathVariable String city){
        return rService.getRestaurantsFromCity(city);
 }
```

You can already test this service with something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en#detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and see that it's working, then on the client side we can call this service using an Ajax request:

```
 $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/city/yourcityId',
     }).success(function(data){
        alert('restaurants: ' + data);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
```

This should print the cities restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way with AngularJs is to load the data from the server using a REST API.  If the data is returned in JSon format it's automatically recognized by AngularJs as Javascript objects and can be added directly to the view.

Here's a simple example using [RESTAngular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['restangular'])

.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('my.api/rest/');
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.city = 'Chicago';
    $scope.restaurants = [{name:'Restaurant 1'}, {name:'Restaurant 2'}];

    // Defines a resource located at "my.api/rest/restaurants/Chicago"
    var source = Restangular.all('restaurants').one($scope.city);

    source.getList().then(function(result) {
        $scope.restaurants = result;
    });
});
```

It's fairly easy to configure Spring MVC to produce JSon data.  I don't know enough to guide you there but you'll find plenty of info out there.